# DataFrame allowed in numpy array

Tags: pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an estimator that accepts a multi-row dataframe as one instance of input.

To grid search through hyperparameters, i need to store by dataset in numpy array .

How can i store a dataframe as items in a 1- D array

```
np.array([pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, ...])
```

Comment: Please don't add incomplete questions. They don't actually provide any information to the user, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you earn enough reputation, you will gain privileges to upvote answers you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See Why is voting important.

Comment: DataFrames store their data as numpy arrays, which can be accessed via the `values` attribute or `to_numpy()` method.  Conceivably you could make an object dtype array, and assign a dataframe to each element.  But why don't you just use a list of dataframes?  What advantage is there in making that list an array?